# Miscibility of pairwise miscible liquids

Tags: physical-chemistry, solubility, immiscibility

If you have a mixture of 3 (or more) liquids which are "pairwise miscible", but which don't react with each other, does that guarantee that the mixture will only have one layer?

By "pairwise miscible", I mean that for every combination of two substances in the mixture, they are miscible with each other, i.e. soluble in all proportions.

For example, ethanol/water/acetone.

Comment: I'll say very probably, but I'd bet that there is a black swan somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

So you want to know whether there is a ternary system with an "island of immiscibility". Well, it turns out that people have thought of this before; such systems [have a name](https://books.google.ru/books?id=I9XIneKdlhQC&lpg=PA47&ots=xQxlLBd4Wr&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q&f=false) ("*type 0 systems*"), and [this paper](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1516-89132013000600020) mentions water/DMSO/THF as an example.
[image: Immiscibility island]